# Unable to update nan values in column using loc?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, pandas-loc

I have stored the index values of all records where the column had missing values in index and I'm trying to impute nan values from another dataframe on the basis of 'StockCode' column common in both dataframes.

This is how df_mod looks like. df is also same but with description as nan. Index is array like [1,2,3,4]
[snapshot of df_mod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHA20.jpg)

```
for i in index:
    if df.loc[i,'StockCode'] in df_mod['StockCode'].values:
        df.loc[i,'Description']=df_mod.loc[(df_mod.StockCode==df.loc[i,'StockCode']),'Description']
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-ada042d0d5a1> in <module>
      1 for i in index:
      2     if df.loc[i,'StockCode'] in df_mod['StockCode'].values:
----> 3         df.loc[i,'Description']=df_mod.loc[(df_mod.StockCode==df.loc[i,'StockCode']),'Description']

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    188             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    189         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 190         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    191 
    192     def _validate_key(self, key, axis):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    467 
    468             if isinstance(value, ABCSeries):
--> 469                 value = self._align_series(indexer, value)
    470 
    471             info_idx = indexer[info_axis]

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _align_series(self, indexer, ser, multiindex_indexer)
    781             return ser.reindex(ax)._values
    782 
--> 783         raise ValueError('Incompatible indexer with Series')
    784 
    785     def _align_frame(self, indexer, df):

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

Answer (score 0):

Without (sample of) your data, it's hard to tell. But this could be a case for `replace`:

```
df['Description'] = df['StockCode'].replace(df_mod.set_index('StockCode')['Description'])
```

Comment: Hi @Quang i have added a snapshot to make it more clear. Could you please help me now